# What's the algorithm used by re.search()

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, python-re

I'm looking into the pattern finding algorithms, for example `boyer_moore_search`. However, `boyer_moore_search` could not handle special symbol such as `\` or `/n` etc. very well. Instead, the `re.search` from the [python's official library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) could be used to perform the pattern matching.

However, the documentation did not outline the algorithms behind the `re.search` nor the complexity involved.

What's the algorithm used by re.search()?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/zpoint/CPython-Internals/blob/master/Modules/re/re.md